# Safe to Encrypt ClientId (Integer value) to use as Client Key?

Tags: encryption, key-generation, client-side

Asked a follow up question ([see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417742/best-practice-to-make-use-of-client-secret-key-in-saas-environment/34419476?noredirect=1#comment56580573_34419476)).

Based on my understanding, I have to issue an unique ClientId and Client Secret Key to the API subscribers right after the registration phase (client lives with those keys forever).

Am thinking to issue just a ClientId (Auto-increment Integer value) to the API subscriber with instructions stating that he must send the Client Id along with Client Secret Key with every request. So, that I can use the ClientId to query the database table and perform a validation on Client Secret Key.

## Questions:

1. Should I encrypt ClientId (Auto-increment Integer value) and Decrypt every time I receive it and perform validations?
2. Currently, the **Client Secret Key** is generated using **SymmetricAlgorithm**.

Thanks!